# How to make a GridView scroll horizontally?

Tags: android

The [Android design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html) lines show a horizontally scrolling grid view. However, I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has been imagined by the Android designers. It is not possible to create horizontal scrolling in a Grid View.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/gHbRBoDVo70